# Bars getting stacked at one place

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can anyone tell me how to provide gaps between the bars that are getting stacked at one particular place?
Here is the code:
P.s: Sorry i tried but coukd not post it as a code snippet due to some error "Please add some explanation"

[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAA8a.jpg)

[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/654cx.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJMwk.jpg)

Comment: "Please add some explanation" means there is too much code and not enough text for questions. Cut out the unnecessary code, state what you tried, and point out the part of your code that should contain what you want.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."*

Comment: Regarding the proposed edit, rejected: putting the images on the question's body makes no difference: OP should not use any image of code.

Answer (score 0):

@Samrat- When appending `rect` to your `svg`, change this line in your code `.attr("x"), function(d,i){return x(i)})` to `.attr("x", (d, i) => i * (svgWidth / info.length))`. This code divides the entire svg width by the length of your dataset and multiplies each value by its index, which distances bars from each other.

Fiddle for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/zfjcLopw/1/

**Here is the updated code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const width = 600;
      const height = 500;
      const margin = { top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 120 };
      const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
      const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      const barPadding = 2;
      const svg = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      const tag = ["mango", "banana", "apple", "lemon", "coconut"];
      const info = [23, 54, 34, 51, 22];

      const xScale = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(tag.map(d => d))
        .rangeRound([0, innerWidth]);

      const yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(info, d => d)])
        .range([innerHeight, 0]);

      const mainG = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

      const g = mainG
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(info)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,0)`);

      g.append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (innerWidth / info.length))
        // .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i)) - This line will stack bars on top of each other
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d))
        .attr("width", innerWidth / info.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", d => innerHeight - yScale(d))
        .attr("fill", "blue");

      mainG.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
      mainG
        .append("g")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

X `scaleBand` domain is set to tag values, but you call it with `i` index. Try `x(tag[i])`