# Why the bars are on top of each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble creating a side by side bar chart.

The bars are getting on top of each other, I would like them to appear side by side.
When you hover you can see that only half the bar changes color. In console.log shows the correct value of them.

```js
    //set up data
    var sales = [
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
            "Vendas_Ano": 21611.950000000004,
            "Vendas_Ant": 16033.31
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
            "Vendas_Ano": 48108.08,
            "Vendas_Ant": 51142.299999999996
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
            "Vendas_Ano": 13427.280000000004,
            "Vendas_Ant": 21274.129999999997
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
            "Vendas_Ano": 28553.83,
            "Vendas_Ant": 15228.569999999998
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
            "Vendas_Ano": 19639.59,
            "Vendas_Ant": 10291.359999999999
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
            "Vendas_Ano": 22530.840000000007,
            "Vendas_Ant": 21905.29
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
            "Vendas_Ano": 20216.759999999995,
            "Vendas_Ant": 8276
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
            "Vendas_Ano": 39832.04,
            "Vendas_Ant": 49810.810000000005
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Set",
            "Vendas_Ano": 12861.52,
            "Vendas_Ant": 24425.32
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Out",
            "Vendas_Ano": 9227.34,
            "Vendas_Ant": 17804.65
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
            "Vendas_Ano": 31382.11,
            "Vendas_Ant": 9993.34
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
            "Vendas_Ano": 39832.04,
            "Vendas_Ant": 36568.7
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
            "Vendas_Ano": 22681.14,
            "Vendas_Ant": 28587.71
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
            "Vendas_Ano": 31382.11,
            "Vendas_Ant": 37637.420000000006
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
            "Vendas_Ano": 32453.779999999995,
            "Vendas_Ant": 32993.12
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
            "Vendas_Ano": 23445.4,
            "Vendas_Ant": 30835.75
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
            "Vendas_Ano": 16471.71,
            "Vendas_Ant": 18028.07
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
            "Vendas_Ano": 11617.470000000001,
            "Vendas_Ant": 22651.53
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
            "Vendas_Ano": 24699.44,
            "Vendas_Ant": 34152.28999999999
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
            "Vendas_Ano": 35476.94000000001,
            "Vendas_Ant": 22069.699999999997
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Set",
            "Vendas_Ano": 37462.92,
            "Vendas_Ant": 23120.08
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Out",
            "Vendas_Ano": 22042.140000000003,
            "Vendas_Ant": 28449.95
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
            "Vendas_Ano": 16471.71,
            "Vendas_Ant": 30755.050000000003
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
            "Vendas_Ano": 24699.44,
            "Vendas_Ant": 22838.64
        }
    ]

    d3.selectAll('input[name=type-selector]').on('change', function () {
        typeSelected = this.value;
        createBar(getDataFromType(typeSelected));
    });

    var typeSelected = d3.select('input[name=type-selector]:checked', '#type-selector').node().value;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // BAR
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var svgBar = d3.select("#myChart").append("svg").attr("width", 600).attr("height", 300);
    var marginBar = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
    };
    var widthBar = +svgBar.attr("width") - marginBar.left - marginBar.right;
    var heightBar = +svgBar.attr("height") - marginBar.top - marginBar.bottom;
    var xBar0 = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, widthBar]).padding(0.1);
    var xBar1 = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, xBar0.bandwidth()]).padding(0.1);
    var yBar = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([heightBar, 0]);
    var gBar = svgBar.append("g").attr('id', 'gBar').attr("transform", "translate(" + marginBar.left + ", " + marginBar.top + ")");

    var gX = gBar.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + heightBar + ")");

    var gY = gBar.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")

    createBar(getDataFromType(typeSelected));

    function createBar(sales) {

        xBar0.domain(sales.map(function (d) {
            return d.MonthAbrev;
        }));

        // xBar1.domain(reduceMonth.map(function (d) {
        //     return d.MonthAbrev;
        // }));

        yBar.domain([0, d3.max(sales, function (d) {
            return d.value
        }) + 15000]);

        gX.call(d3.axisBottom(xBar0.padding(0.6)));
        gY.call(d3.axisLeft(yBar))
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", "0.71em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end");

        var bars = gBar.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(sales);

        bars.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .merge(bars)
            .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (widthBar / sales.length))
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return yBar(d.value);
            })
            .attr("width", xBar0.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                return heightBar - yBar(d.value);
            })
            .on("mouseover", function (a) {
                console.log(a);
                bars.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "title-text")
                    .style("fill", "rgb(44, 160, 44)")
                    .text(
                        a.vendnm
                    )
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("x", 400)
                    .attr("y", 50);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (a) {
                bars.select(".title-text").remove();
            })
    }

    // return the right data
    function getDataFromType(type) {
        var arr = [];
        sales.forEach(function (item) {
            arr.push({
                "vendnm": item.vendnm,
                "MonthAbrev": item.MonthAbrev,
                "value": item[type]
            });
        });
        return arr;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<head>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

</head>

<style>
    .bar {
        fill: steelblue;
    }

    .bar:hover {
        fill: brown;
    }

    .arc text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        text-anchor: middle;
    }

    .arc path {
        stroke: #fff;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div style="margin: 20px">
        <div style="margin-left: 50px;" id="type-selector-container">
            <form id='type-selector'>
                <input type='radio' name='type-selector' id='rb-1' value='Vendas_Ano' checked />
                <label for='rb-1'>Vendas Ano</label>

                <input type='radio' name='type-selector' id='rb-2' value='Vendas_Ant' />
                <label for='rb-2'>Vendas Ant</label>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="myChart"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm beginner in D3.js and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @vbernal- This post might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948410/bars-getting-stacked-at-one-place/57959423#57959423

Comment: Hii @ksp585, I edited the line `.attr (" x ", function (d, i) { return xBar0 (d.MonthAprev); })` and put `.attr ("x", (d, i) => i * (widthBar / sales.length))`.
I've edited here in the code too, the problem now is that first appears 12 bars of Seller A (Heath) and then 12 bars of Seller B (João Luis). Do you know how I can do to appear interspersed? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by basically changing my 'x' function.
Now it looks like this:

```js
    //set up data
    var sales = [
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
            "Vendas_Ano": 21611.950000000004,
            "Vendas_Ant": 16033.31
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
            "Vendas_Ano": 48108.08,
            "Vendas_Ant": 51142.299999999996
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
            "Vendas_Ano": 13427.280000000004,
            "Vendas_Ant": 21274.129999999997
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
            "Vendas_Ano": 28553.83,
            "Vendas_Ant": 15228.569999999998
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
            "Vendas_Ano": 19639.59,
            "Vendas_Ant": 10291.359999999999
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
            "Vendas_Ano": 22530.840000000007,
            "Vendas_Ant": 21905.29
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
            "Vendas_Ano": 20216.759999999995,
            "Vendas_Ant": 8276
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
            "Vendas_Ano": 39832.04,
            "Vendas_Ant": 49810.810000000005
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Set",
            "Vendas_Ano": 12861.52,
            "Vendas_Ant": 24425.32
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Out",
            "Vendas_Ano": 9227.34,
            "Vendas_Ant": 17804.65
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
            "Vendas_Ano": 31382.11,
            "Vendas_Ant": 9993.34
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
            "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
            "Vendas_Ano": 39832.04,
            "Vendas_Ant": 36568.7
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
            "Vendas_Ano": 22681.14,
            "Vendas_Ant": 28587.71
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
            "Vendas_Ano": 31382.11,
            "Vendas_Ant": 37637.420000000006
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
            "Vendas_Ano": 32453.779999999995,
            "Vendas_Ant": 32993.12
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
            "Vendas_Ano": 23445.4,
            "Vendas_Ant": 30835.75
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
            "Vendas_Ano": 16471.71,
            "Vendas_Ant": 18028.07
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
            "Vendas_Ano": 11617.470000000001,
            "Vendas_Ant": 22651.53
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
            "Vendas_Ano": 24699.44,
            "Vendas_Ant": 34152.28999999999
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
            "Vendas_Ano": 35476.94000000001,
            "Vendas_Ant": 22069.699999999997
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Set",
            "Vendas_Ano": 37462.92,
            "Vendas_Ant": 23120.08
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Out",
            "Vendas_Ano": 22042.140000000003,
            "Vendas_Ant": 28449.95
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
            "Vendas_Ano": 16471.71,
            "Vendas_Ant": 30755.050000000003
        },
        {
            "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
            "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
            "Vendas_Ano": 24699.44,
            "Vendas_Ant": 22838.64
        }
    ]

    d3.selectAll('input[name=type-selector]').on('change', function () {
        typeSelected = this.value;
        createBar(getDataFromType(typeSelected));
    });

    var typeSelected = d3.select('input[name=type-selector]:checked', '#type-selector').node().value;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // BAR
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var svgBar = d3.select("#myChart").append("svg").attr("width", 600).attr("height", 300);
    var marginBar = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
    };
    var widthBar = +svgBar.attr("width") - marginBar.left - marginBar.right;
    var heightBar = +svgBar.attr("height") - marginBar.top - marginBar.bottom;
    var xBar0 = d3.scaleBand().range([0, widthBar]).padding(0.1);
    var yBar = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([heightBar, 0]);
    var gBar = svgBar.append("g").attr('id', 'gBar').attr("transform", "translate(" + marginBar.left + ", " + marginBar.top + ")");

    var gX = gBar.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + heightBar + ")");

    var gY = gBar.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")

    createBar(getDataFromType(typeSelected));

    function createBar(sales) {

        xBar0.domain(sales.map(function (d) {
            return d.MonthAbrev;
        }));

        yBar.domain([0, d3.max(sales, function (d) {
            return d.value
        }) + 15000]);

        var barWidth = xBar0.bandwidth() / 2;

        gX.call(d3.axisBottom(xBar0));
        gY.call(d3.axisLeft(yBar))
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", "0.71em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end");

        var bars = gBar.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(sales);

            // console.log

        bars.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .merge(bars)
            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                return xBar0(d.MonthAbrev) + barWidth * ((d.vendnm == 'CHARNECA') ? 0.2 : 1);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return yBar(d.value);
            })
            .attr("width", barWidth - 5)
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                // console.log(d);
                return heightBar - yBar(d.value);
            })
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                if (d.vendnm === 'CHARNECA') {
                    return "rgb(251,180,174)";
                } else {
                    return "rgb(179,205,227)";
                }
            })
            .on("mouseover", function (a) {
                gBar.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "title-text")
                    .style("fill", "#000000")
                    .text(
                        a.vendnm + ' - ' +
                        a.MonthAbrev + ' - ' +
                        Number(Math.round(a.value * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }) + '€'
                    )
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("x", 200)
                    .attr("y", 30);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (a) {
                gBar.select(".title-text").remove();
            })
    }

    // return the right data
    function getDataFromType(type) {
        var arr = [];
        sales.forEach(function (item) {
            arr.push({
                "vendnm": item.vendnm,
                "MonthAbrev": item.MonthAbrev,
                "value": item[type]
            });
        });
        return arr;
    }
```

```html
<head>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

</head>

<style>
    .bar:hover {
        fill: brown;
    }

    .arc text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        text-anchor: middle;
    }

    .arc path {
        stroke: #fff;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div style="margin: 20px">
        <div style="margin-left: 50px;" id="type-selector-container">
            <form id='type-selector'>
                <input type='radio' name='type-selector' id='rb-1' value='Vendas_Ano' checked />
                <label for='rb-1'>Vendas_Ano</label>

                <input type='radio' name='type-selector' id='rb-2' value='Vendas_Ant' />
                <label for='rb-2'>Vendas_Ant</label>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="myChart"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```